# Custom button in List View

Tags: list-view

[image]

I had create the custom button in Account (in list view). If i click that particular button, it has to redirect to custom vf page.

Comment: on click of above button,i wanted to redirectd to AutoCompletePage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your content Source is URL, you should have URL instead of Hyperlink formula.

Try with:

> /apex/AccountAutoComplete